# Этимология слова Бизнес?

Tags: этимология

Или, если быть точнее, слова "Business"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В современном английском существительное business (занятие, дело) связано с прилагательным busy (занятый) через суффикс -ness. В староанглийском *bisignes* первоначально (до середины 14 века) означало состояние сильной занятости, суету и беспокойство, будучи образовано от *bisig* (тщательный, обеспокоенный, занятый, прилежный). В значении рода занятий человека слово употреблялось с 14 века, а в значении профессиональной, коммерческой деятельности употребляется с начала 18 века. В русский слово заимствовано в соответствии с его современным (двусложным) английским произношением (17 век).

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=business

Comment: А точно ли  это заимствование 17 века, в словарях указывается начало 20 века,в  Советскую эпоху?

Comment: У меня указано не время заимствования слова, а время перехода к современному произношению в английском (с ним связано русское написание слова).

Comment: Спасибо большое, просто у меня с английским так себе, а на русском подобной информации я не встречал.